# Use ASP.NET MVC routing to modify an incoming url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Is there any way of adding a route mapping in Global.asax so that routes that contain a certain string (say "Content") are mapped to a different url (say "Content/gz") if a certain http header is present?

Comment: what do you mean by "if a certain http header is present"?

Comment: For example if there's a header in the HTTP request specifying that the browser allows gzipped content.

Comment: HTTP Requests can be dealt with in the controller, which can return different results based on the request.  would that work for your scenario?  Or, do you mean that you need to reach a different controller based on the http header?

Comment: I need this to work without using controllers. What I'd like is to have the server serve up gzipped images if the browser allows for them.

Comment: If your specific question is about gzipped static content, then IIS and ASP.NET can take care of this automatically. But I'm guessing there's a general question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up fixing it by keeping a global Content url that gets updated on each request depending on the presence of the accept-gzip header is present.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the header in the Content controller and do a redirect to Content/gz if it's gzipped.

Comment: Content is not a controller, it's a folder where different images and css files are found.

Comment: generally speaking "content" folders for images and CSS files are ignored for routing purposes so that calls to those files don't end up at a controller.  Maybe routing isn't want you're looking for - how do you "serve up" these images?  are they embedded in your view?

Comment: "Is there any way of adding a route mapping in Global.asax so that routes that contain a certain string (say "Content") are mapped to a different url (say "Content/gz") if a certain http header is present?" That was the original question, I answered it assuming he knew that "Content" could not be an actual controller.